# Input file loops

Tags: java, loops, input

Basically I have to write up a fairly simple code. But cannot figure some parts out. We just learned material concerning loops and such. And our assignment is to write code that will take the student info from an output file. Name, address, Account number and their credits taken. Then calculate their bill, and print it to an output file. So far  I have most of the code done I believe, but I believe we need to use loops in this program which is stumping me. Because its not taking info from just 1 student, it is up to 3. So I'm not to sure if I'm looping it correctly, so far I have a while loop in use to keep reading until the end of the text. But I cannot tell if it works properly because of something strange.

When I try to output the info, it says 3 variables are not initialized and I'm almost certain it is. Anyway, here is my code. Any tips on looping the input and outputs would be much appreciated!

/*
 */

```
package program4;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Program4 {

// Sets the prices for full time and part time students.

static final double TUITION_PER_CREDIT = 276.00;
static final double FEE_PER_CREDIT     = 15.00;
static final double SERVICE_PER_CREDIT = 7.09;
static final double FULL_TIME_TUITION  = 3311.00;
static final double FULL_TIME_FEE      = 184.00;
static final double FULL_TIME_SERVICE  = 85.00;


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{

    int i                       ;
    String firstName      =null ;
    String lastName       =null ;
    String accountNumber  =null ;
    double creditsTaken = 0     ;
    String address1             ;
    String address, address2, address3, address4, address5, address6;      
    String fileName             ;
    double tuition      = 0     ;
    double fees         = 0     ;
    double total        = 0     ;
    String formatFees           ;
    String formatTotal          ;
    String formatTuition        ;

            //create a scanner object named inFile and assign it the file input.dat
            fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the input file name. ");

            Scanner inFile = new Scanner (new FileReader(fileName));

            //create a PrintWriter object named outFile associated with the file output.dat
            PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter ("tuitionAndFees.dat");


            //Intended to loop the input until the end of the file.

    while (inFile.hasNext())
    {   firstName     = inFile.next();
        lastName      = inFile.next();
        address       = inFile.next();
        address2      = inFile.next();
        address3      = inFile.next();
        address4      = inFile.next();
        address5      = inFile.next();
        address6      = inFile.next();
        accountNumber = inFile.next();
        creditsTaken  = inFile.nextDouble();
    }  

    //If Else statement to determine if the student is a part time or full time student, and then calculates their bill.
        if(creditsTaken < 12)
        {   tuition = TUITION_PER_CREDIT * creditsTaken;
            fees    =(FEE_PER_CREDIT + SERVICE_PER_CREDIT) * creditsTaken;
            total   = tuition + fees;

            formatTotal   = String.format("%.2f", total);
            formatFees    = String.format("%.2f", fees);
            formatTuition = String.format("%.2f", tuition);
        }

        else
        {
            tuition = FULL_TIME_TUITION;
            fees    = FULL_TIME_FEE +  FULL_TIME_SERVICE;
            total   = tuition + fees;

            formatTotal   = String.format("%.2f", total);
            formatFees    = String.format("%.2f", fees);
            formatTuition = String.format("%.2f", tuition);
        }

       //Output to file all info, needs fixed.
       outFile.println("Tuition Billing Report ");
       outFile.printf("CWID\t\t Name\t\t Credits\t\t Tuition\t\t Fees\t\t Total%n");

       System.out.printf(accountNumber, firstName, lastName, creditsTaken, formatTuition, formatFees, formatTotal);

       inFile.close();
       outFile.close();

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The program was saved in tuitionAndFees.dat");



    } 
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample data file>?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a variable unless it has been initialized. You have written your initialization inside a while block and there is a condition for entering the while block. Which means that there is a possibiblity that the initialization might never happen (in case the file has no lines to read). Java performs a check for these conditions. In order to remove these errors, you can initialize them to a default value at the declaration line. For all the integers, you have initialized them to 0, similarly Strings can be initialized to null or an empty string.

From [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html).

`Each local variable (§14.4) and every blank final field (§4.12.4, §8.3.1.2) must have a definitely assigned value when any access of its value occurs.`

`The idea behind definite assignment is that an assignment to the local variable or blank final field must occur on every possible execution path to the access.`

This means that the variable must have a value no matter what execution path it follows. In your case, it should have a value no matter if it enters the while block or not; even if you are pretty sure that it will.

Also, after you read each file you might want to save the values some place as you would be needing the same variables again in the second iteration to hold the values from the next line. You end up overwriting the values otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

`AccountNumber`, `firstName` and `lastName` could be empty if the file is empty. Give them default values.

Also, variables should start with a lower case letter, `AccountNumber` should be `accountNumber`

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact it's not going to work anyway. your Variable problem is these 3:

```
String firstName       ;
String lastName        ;
String AccountNumber   ;
```

These haven't been initialised. and because this is conditional:

```
while (inFile.hasNext(fileName)) {
    firstName     = inFile.next();
    lastName      = inFile.next();
    ...
    AccountNumber = inFile.next();
}
```

They may never get initialised. To initialise a String (because it's an object) you need to add = null to their declaration.

e.g.

```
String firstName = null;
```

Now, regarding the functionality. You are looping through the file correctly. However, every time you go round you overwrite the variables. This means your processing logic only happens for the last person in the file. Unless you've already cover OOP, then you probably just need to move your processing logic up into the while loop (but not the file closing, and confirmation line).

Comment: So far you've been a big help. the initialization was the minor problem I was having. With the input file loop, I'm glad to see that I am looping it correctly, and I was figuring that the data was going to be over written.

But before I can continue testing the code. after making the changes, it has given me a new error. Here is a screenshot. http://puu.sh/5H7nj.png

Comment: Its hard to say exactly, but at a guess, i'd say it's because one or more of the values is still null, so it can't format it. try putting a System.out.println before your printf to see what's in each one, then you can figure out which one is null.

Comment: Also, i think you want to change this: inFile.hasNext(fileName) to this inFile.hasNext()

Comment: So far it just prints the account number, and nothing else.

Comment: can you update the code above with what you have now, and give some sample data so I can run it myself

Comment: Done! Really appreciate you're help!

Comment: Forgot the input data as well. Sorry!

Dom Pilorusso
1037 Waterford Court
Canonsburg PA 15317
C937493021
15

Dan Madeupname
106 Cidar Lane
McMurray PA 15317
C927012312
11

Steve Arnold
281 Maple Drive
Canonsburg PA 15317
C482716209
9

Comment: ah, right, your problem is with the second printf. the first parameter is the format, the remaining objects are the inputs to the format. as there are no inputs in the format, its not printing them out, and just printing the format itself (which in this case if the account number). Personally I would just build up the data into a formatted string, and print it directly.

Comment: What about the input loop? Is it taking all the info? Or is it overwriting it?

Comment: you are still overwriting with only the last record